# Django: parameters + date named groups in urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I have in my urls.py this:

```
---urls.py---
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       (r'^queryinfo3/(.*)/(.*)/(?P<year>\d{4})-(?P<month>\d{2})-(?P<day>\d{2})/$', queryInfo3),
```

The above code hopefully matches such kind of request:

```
http://localhost:8081/queryinfo3/text1/text2/2012-02-07/
```

on my views.py, I have this handler method:

```
def queryInfo3(request, sname, urlkey, year=None, month=None, day=None):
       return HttpResponse("something")
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this TypeError:

```
queryInfo3() takes at least 3 arguments (4 given)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
I tried this:

```
def queryInfo3(request, sname, urlkey, year, month, day):
     ...
```

But I am getting a TypeError still:

```
queryInfo3() takes exactly 6 arguments (4 given)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have two urls for that because the other 3 values are equal to None

```
(r'^queryinfo3/(\w+)/(\w+)/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})/(?P<day>\d{1,2})/$', queryInfo3),
```

Test:

```
 localhost:8081/queryinfo3/text1/text2/2012/02/07
```

**OR**

```
 (r'^queryinfo3/(\w+)/(\w+)/(?P<year>\d{4})-(?P<month>\d{1,2})-(?P<day>\d{1,2})/$', queryInfo3),
```

Test:

```
 localhost:8081/queryinfo3/text1/text2/2012-02-07
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Cathy. But it's not working. Still the same typeerror. And I am quite confused with your reply...why should I have 2 urls defined?

Comment: Because you set year, month, and day to None as default. So user can have the option not to enter year, month, and day.

Comment: what if i don't set it to None? just def queryInfo3(request, sname, urlkey, year, month, day):

Comment: I get this error now queryInfo3() takes exactly 6 arguments (4 given)

Comment: If you dont set it to None you can have only one url. Update your question with templates. I need it.

Comment: sorry but what do you mean with templates? I don't use any forms here

Comment: your template codes (.html). How you call that url? I need to see it.

Comment: it's above... via browser, i test it like this http://localhost:8081/queryinfo3/text1/text2/2012-02-07/

Comment: ok code updated and test like this  localhost:8081/queryinfo3/text1/text2/2012/02/07

Comment: thanks for the update. But on views.py, how should I handle this? I tested your update on def queryInfo3(request, sname, urlkey, year=None, month=None, day=None): handler but I am getting an error

Comment: queryInfo3() takes at least 3 arguments (4 given). Can you post your views.py?